# How do you handle invalid characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, punctuation

I just started converting the data on my site from XML to MySQL and I am running into some syntax errors when I use this puncuation mark: '

Is there any way to let MySQL know about that character. Like in Java you would use a forward slash to put quotation marks in a string.

Hopefully I explained this well enough. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the same fashion with backslash

```
'Look at me, I\'m a string'
```

More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html).

Comment: The link in the `More information here.` is not found. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not parameterizing your arguments when calling MySQL. If you use parameterization, you won't have to deal with character escaping, and the whole host of reliability and security problems that can come with it. Trust me, parameterization is worth the effort.

You didn't specify what client framework you're using, but if you're using Java, look into [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). **EDIT**: OP is using PHP, so the [PHP documentation on prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) would be good reading.

Comment: No Java was just an example. I'm actually using PHP. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sightofnick: Ah. Then the [PHP documentation on prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) would be the place to start.